# bootstrap by group and calculate statistics

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics-bootstrap, purrr

I'm trying to bootstrap some model fits and then calculate statistics without having to rerun the models every time. I can do this fine if I calculate r2 inside the first `do()` but I'd like to know how to access the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(modelr)
library(purrr)

allmdls <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do({
    datsplit=crossv_mc(.,10)
    mdls=list(map(datsplit$train, ~glm(hp~disp,data=.,family=gaussian(link='identity'))))
    data_frame(datsplit=list(datsplit),mdls)
  })
```

and now something like:

```
allmdls %>%
  by_slice(dmap,.f=map2_dbl(.$mdls,.$datsplit$test,rsquare))
```

but I get

> Error: `.y` is not a vector (NULL)

or

```
allmdls %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   do({
     map2_df(.x=.$mdls, .y=.$datsplit, .f=map2_dbl(.x=.x,.y=.y$test,.f=rsquare))
   })
```

> Error in map2_dbl(.x = .x, .y = .y$test, .f = rsquare) :    object
>   '.x' not found

I can't seem to get the syntax right.

help?
Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks to @aosmith's comment, I created a somewhat simpler solution:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do({
    datplit=crossv_mc(.,10) %>% 
      mutate(mdls=map(train, ~glm(hp~disp,data=.)),
             r2=map2_dbl(mdls,test,rsquare)
             pctmae=map2_dbl(mdls,test,function(model,data) {mae(model,data)/mean(model$model$hp,na.rm=T)*100})
      )
  })
```

Comment: These list of lists seem realtively hard to work with.  You can do `mutate(allmdls, rsq = map2(mdls, map(datsplit, "test"), ~map2(.x, .y, rsquare)))` with nested `map2`s so you are working on the innermost lists.  Maybe there is something that you can do with `at_depth`, as well, but not sure when working with multiple lists of lists like this.

Comment: @aosmith  I uncovered a variation on your solution that is simpler and mostly works so thanks for the inspiration. I agree the lists in lists is not ideal.
How did you know/ what is happening with "test" in quotes?

Comment: Cool, you should put it as a solution.  The `map(datsplit, "test")` it to extract the test column from `datsplit` as dollar sign notation and extract brackets weren't working.  The documentation for `map` has a fairly good explanation of this for `.f`.

Comment: ah i see. I was thinking about .f as a function but it can also be a character or integer vector to extract columns

@aosmith If you post your comment I'll accept it. I'll add my solution too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `map2` within `mutate`.  Because you are using lists of lists I ended up with nested `map2`s to get access to the innermost lists.  I pulled the `test` data out via `map(datsplit, "test")`, as neither the dollar sign operator nor the extract brackets were working for me.

```
mutate(allmdls, rsq = map2(mdls, map(datsplit, "test"), ~map2_dbl(.x, .y, rsquare)))
```

Here is another option that avoids the nested lists all together:

```
mtcars %>%
    split(.$cyl) %>%
    map_df(crossv_mc, 10, .id = "cyl") %>%
    mutate(models = map(train, ~glm(hp ~ disp, data = .x)),
          rsq = map2_dbl(models, test, rsquare))
```

Answer (score 1):

@aosmith answered my question but here is a simpler solution overall

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do({
    datplit=crossv_mc(.,10) %>% 
      mutate(mdls=map(train, ~glm(hp~disp,data=.)),
             r2=map2_dbl(mdls,test,rsquare)
             pctmae=map2_dbl(mdls,test,function(model,data) {mae(model,data)/mean(model$model$hp,na.rm=T)*100})
      )
  })
```